# How to underline numbers in an input or textarea using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a textarea inputbox and I want to know is there any way to underline the number values in this input box than using regular expressions (I don't really understand them).

here's my changeAll() function that does nothing really but get the value from the input box and it will change a different div element(my output box) to the newly underlined output:

```
changeAll = function(){
var x = document.getElementById('input').value;
//underline numbers ....
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = y;
}
```

I also know that the CSS is just

```
#number { 
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Any help on how to do this in an easier way than regular expressions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is your real question how to determine if variable `x` is a number?  In which case there are LOTS of questions and answers on StackOverflow about verifying/checking if things are numbers.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I guess he's trying to apply styles to the content, like rich editor.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with `input` or `textarea`. I would do it with a `contenteditable` container.

Comment: sorry if i wasn't clear enough.. if the user enters a number value into the text area i want the number it be underlined so if the user enteres "Hello 7" it would be changed to "Hello (underlined)7(underlined)"

Comment: @Leo I got that, but detecting numbers seemed to be part of his question, and I didn't feel like playing around to see if his proposed CSS worked. Somewhere inside this vague question is a specific question, struggling to get out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a regular expression:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var output = document.getElementById("output");

input.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
  output.innerHTML = input.value.replace(
    /(\d+)/g, "<span style=\"text-decoration:underline\">$1</span>"
  );
});
```

```html
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Without a regular expression:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var output = document.getElementById("output");

input.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
  var open = false;
  var digit = false;
  var x = this.value, y = "";
  var i, n = x.length;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    digit = x[i] >= '0' && x[i] <= '9';
    if (digit && !open) {
      open = true;
      y += "<span style=\"text-decoration:underline\">";
    } else if (!digit && open) {
      open = false;
      y += "</span>";
    }
    y += x[i];
  }
  output.innerHTML = y;
});
```

```html
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: thanks that worked perfectly. I changed the regular expression one into a function and it's working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in a textarea. However, there is a little trick you can apply, and that is using a textarea that is totally transparent where the user types in, listening to any change to the value of the textarea and rendering it on top of another element where you do the actual display of the content. Since that can be any type of element, you can apply any styling you wish there. Of course, for the caret to appear correctly, you would need the exact same font as in the textarea.

Most browser-based editors with syntax-highlighting work that way.

I would advise against using contenteditable for this, because that would effectively allow any markup to end up in your container.

Comment: or use a `<div>` with content editable. I would use this instead of the transparent `<textarea>` since it is easier.

Comment: `contenteditable` +1, which is more powerful. For example you can never display an image in textarea, but contenteditable div can.

Comment: Yes, plus the user can copy paste anything in there leaving you with the trouble of cleaning up the data :) Depends on the use case, but just for underlining numbers I wouldn't use it.